# Linking a custom Object's field to a Custom Setting's field?

Tags: relationships

I was trying to get a custom object's field 'Report' to auto-populate by linking to a field in Custom Settings, 'Id'. Is there a way to do this using a look-up relationship? Or maybe there is another way of doing this that I am not aware of.. I am a bit new to Salesforce development so go easy. :)

Comment: There isn't anyway to link an object with custom setting. But we can query custom setting from a trigger and can use the results within the trigger. Custom settings are like global variables that can be accessed from any object's trigger or from process builder etc.

Comment: Check this answer as an example of custom settings usage in a trigger. `https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/180422/16659`

Comment: If the custom setting field I am trying to access is a 'list' instead of a 'heirarchy', does this affect the use of triggers?

Comment: No it isn't. The change will be only related to how you retrieve data from hierarchical custom setting. There is a minor difference you can check the docs for hierarchy custom setting. `https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm`

Comment: If it is helpful can I convert it to an answer?

Comment: This was helpful, but the custom setting is a list, any idea on where to start looking to create that trigger, so far I've been looking on youtube and they've been heirarchy triggers not lists.

Comment: What you want? Hierarchy or list custom setting?

Comment: So this is the overview... there is a custom setttings field called 'Ops' inside of Ops there is a list called 'Id', I need to pull that Id from the custom settings field to populate a field in a custom object called 'Car'. I am still trying to figure out what exactly that trigger would look like.

Comment: Those Ids will contain the latest updated value or it is a static list of Ids which you just want to assign to the field of Custom object Car?

Comment: There is 2 Id fields in Car. One for Idenitfication purposes and one for registration. The user should be able to enter an identification number and the registration Id number will auto-populate from the field 'Id' inside of the custom settings object 'Ops'

Comment: When creating a record^*

Comment: That means it will be unique for every car and you'll maintain all those IDs in custom setting. If this is the case then it is really really a bad idea.

Comment: Well these the Ids that car is pulling from Ops IS static. So the registration number just needs to be associated with that field correct?

Comment: Ah... I see. Then its understandable.

Comment: Any way you could get the ball rolling for me as to what that trigger would look like?

Comment: I'll do it just looking for a less busy slot.

Comment: Of time. Very stuffed with work nowadays.

Comment: Okay no worries! Just let me know if you can do it! I'm working on something myself, but I'm not sure if it is even remotely close.

Comment: I can try it tomorrow.

Comment: I was just looking at your comments and find out that the link to an answer I provided you already is exactly what you looking for according to my understanding. Here is the link https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/180422/16659

Comment: That looks like code that auto-generates a nickname, I need a field that links back to a custom settings field and auto-populates it based on those records. Not auto-generate a new Id number.

Answer (score 1):

I think the look-up relationship is better.

Comment: But is there a way to do this? I don't think you can just link a field of a Custom Object to a field in Custom settings using a look up relationship.